# How to change the row height in pgAdmin on 4K monitors with scale >1

Tags: ubuntu, pgadmin, pgadmin3

the row height in pgAdmin is controlled by the font size, but on my 2160p screen I'm using scale factor x2 to render readable UIs. The font is cut in the result grid, I can expand manually.

[image]

Are there any option to control the row height? Somewhere in ~/.pgadmin3?

Comment: Try to use the `Consolas` font and see if it helps.

Comment: @hkdtam `Consolas` make no difference, I've played with other fonts and it is all the same, only putting `scaling-factor 1` makes things in order and I can use it normally on 1080p screen. In any case thanks!

Comment: Nice and I learn something, thanks.  Perhaps you can make your own answer here?

Comment: for sure once it is resolved, have no much luck yet.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Eduardo I end up using DBeaver for data manipulating and pgAdmin for query plan and sql schema extraction, since DBeaver does not do it well.